# Convert query from Oracle to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to convert below **Oracle** query into **SQL server** environment-

```
select to_date(substr(to_char(col1, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS),1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') from tab;
```

From the above query i want to convert it into first time in **Date format** and then second time **Time format**. It means two times i want this query while above one in **Date format**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not even how I would do this in Oracle.  This is converting the date/time value to a date, with no time component.  In SQL Server:

```
select cast(col1 as date)
from tab;
```

In Oracle:

```
select trunc(col1)
from tab;
```